# Laravel URL::previous without domain

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to get only the path of the previous page? Like URL::previous() but without the whole domain like `/something`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote my own function for this:

In vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php i added

```
public function previousPath()
{
        $parsed = parse_url($this->previous());

        return $parsed['path'];
}
```

beneath the `previous()` function, now you can do `URL::previousPath()` which returns only the path without the domain.

Comment: This is not a good idea to modify the core class, instead you can write it in somewhere else, once you update the current version, your changes will be gone.